# Removing the gaps between two vector layers and merge them seamlessly

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I have multiple vector files  needed to merge them without any error, but there is gap between one layer and another layer as shown in image 1 respectively. How can I rectify this error?

[image: Image-1]

I merged the layer files but I can see the gap in the layer as shown in Image-2.

[image: image 2]

PS: All the operations are carried out in QGIS.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Use snap tool and edit by hand

Comment: How big is the gap and should the vertical black lines meet at their ends? You could use the snap tool or GRASS v.clean with different tolerances and see if they get what you want without creating other unacceptable. changes.  You could even select and move a whole layer with snapping on to match another if the gap is consistent. If your different layers were in different coordinate systems and the gaps are unexpected you might first try some other transformations to see if they close the gaps prior to merging.

Comment: Thanks for your Valuable comments will try it.